# Finding radial acceleration from $xy$ vector cordinate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, coordinate-systems, acceleration, vectors

I know that is a silly question but i cant figure it out.
Suppose we have
$$ \textbf{R} = A i + B j  $$
and want to find the radial acceleration.
We know that the radial acceleration is
$$  \ddot{r}  - r\dot{\theta}^ 2 $$
I tried to write x and y hats of the $$ \ddot{R}=\ddot{A}i+\ddot{B}j $$ in spherical unit vectors(bunch of cos and sin) and at the end the r hat component appeared to be
$$ \ddot{A}*cos + \ddot{B}*sin $$
But I can't see that the magnitude of this thing is equal to the magnitude of
$$ \ddot{A} + \ddot{B} $$
Like how mytextbook says.
Where I'm wrong?

Comment: It doesn't affect the essence of your question, but shouldn't the radial acceleration have a minus sign, i.e. $  \ddot{r}  - r\dot{\theta}^ 2 $? You do not appear to be wrong. Perhaps there is a typo in your book or a notation issue. For example, should your last line be $\vec{\ddot{A}}+\vec{\ddot{B}}$ or $\ddot{\mathbf{A}}+\ddot{\mathbf{B}}$?

Comment: Why did you use boldface for $\mathbf R$ but not for $i$ and $j$? They’re vectors too.

Comment: The convention notation for the Cartesian components of $\mathbf R$ is $x$ and $y$, not $A$ and $B$.

Comment: *Where I'm wrong?* You gave your result without showing any of the intermediate steps, so it is impossible to know what mistake you made.

Comment: $cos$ and $sin$ are meaningless. You have to take the cosine and sine of an *angle*.

Comment: @DavidBailey oh yes, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The radial acceleration is *not* $\ddot A + \ddot B$. To see this, consider the case where $A(t) = t^2$ and $B(t) = t^2$, so

$\vec {R(t)} = t^2 \vec i + t^2 \vec j$

and we have $r(t) = (\sqrt 2)t^2$ and $\theta(t) = \frac {\pi} 4$.

Since $\theta(t)$ is constant we have $\dot \theta=0$ and so the radial acceleration is just $\ddot r$, which is $2 \sqrt2$. But $\ddot A = \ddot B = 2$, so $\ddot A + \ddot B = 4 \ne \ddot r$.

Comment: I think the same! Maybe it is a typo in the book